# Update image divs with data from API

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm really new to JavaScript and I'm trying to develop a website that pulls data from this API - https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/, and displays the image from each object in the homepage.

However, I've been fiddling with the JavaScript and the image elements are not updating correctly in the page. Instead of each image div representing a different object and its image (much like a "pinterest" style page), the divs are being updated at the same time with all the images.

The goal in the end is to retrieve the data from one objectID, update a card div with that data, and move on to the next objectID, and so on...

```
let currentObject = 34;
const limit = 100; 

const getObjects = async () => {

   const res = await fetch(`https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${currentObject}`);
   const data = await res.json();

   if (currentObject <= limit) {
       
       getObjects();
       

   const imagesArray = document.getElementsByClassName("card-img");

       for (var i = 0, x = imagesArray.length; i < x; i++) {
           imagesArray[i].src = currentObject.primaryImage;

           currentObject++;
       }
       
   } else {
       return;
   }

}
getObjects();
```

Appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your goal, I believe you should replace the function `getObjects` with `getObject` and make it focus on one task: get an object:

```
const getObject = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${currentObject}`
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

Then, you could have another async function to handle the looping:

```
const imagesArray = document.getElementsByClassName("card-img");
const limit = 100;
let currentObject = 34;

async function run() {
  for (let i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
    if (currentObject <= limit) {
      const currentObject = await getObject(imageIndex);
      imagesArray[imageIndex].src = currentObject.primaryImage;
      currentObject++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
run();
```